# Just registered in bitcoin core...Gave my address for receiving, how long it takes for 1st transaction?

Tags: transactions

I am a newbie in bitcoins.Created a btc core, and from file>receiving addresses, i copied and send the address to the sender. Still waiting for the transaction ( 11 hours+), is this normal, and how do we speed up the process?

Comment: Is your client fully synchronized with the network? You won't see a transaction until you've synchronized past the point that transaction was confirmed.

Comment: Yeah, thanks it's not fully synchronized and it looks like it will take forever, since syncronizing 1 week took something like several hours.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your Bitcoin Core client should be fully synchronized with the network, as @PieterWuille stated. This means your client should download and validate the entire blockchain. This may take a while to do because of the current size of the blockchain that is at roughly 124 Gb (Go have a look [here](https://bitinfocharts.com/)). This is why this process might take a long while to complete, and your wallet will only reflect your transaction after it has synchronized.

However there are other possibilities that you can use if you aren't looking into heavy bitcoin mining and usage, or for starting purposes. You can have a look at bitcoin wallets (eg. Multibit, Bitcoin Wallet, and Breadwallet just naming a few) rather than looking at bitcoin core, just for starting out. There are also some nice online wallets and mobile wallets you can use, however, all wallets have some pros and cons to them, and maybe the best thing will be is to first read up about all the different wallets available, the main bitcoin site is a nice starting place together with the bitcoin wiki.

However, there is a small catch. Because your bitcoin has already been sent to your bitcoin core receiving address and is currently in the blockchain, you will have to wait for it to completely download to receive that bitcoin, or you can maybe read up on transferring your private keys but I am not very familiar with this and thus not sure if it will work.

Comment: Thank you too for the answer, I guess I just did not registered at the right place. The synchronize is really taking way too long, not even close to finish after 3 days. For a small amount of money, bitcoin core is really the wrong place

Comment: Yeah, bitcoin core is if you want to go all in ! If my answer solved your question please accept my answer . So that the thread can be closed @bbb